# The type SlidingActivity cannot be a superinterface of MainActivity; a superinterface must be an interface

Tags: android

I am trying to use ActionBArSherlock and SlidingMenu in my Application.
I have imported the libraries. My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

But I get the following error on **SlidingActivity**

```
The type SlidingActivity cannot be a superinterface of MainActivity; a superinterface must be an interface
```

Comment: which apis have you used ??? and come on chat dear

Comment: is your problem get solved???

Comment: yes..it got solved !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `SlidingActivity` is not an interface. You can not implement it.

Second, you can not extend two class into single class.

**Solution**

Go into the `SlidingMenu` library and extend the `Activity` by `SherlockFragmentActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`.

Then just extend `SlidingActivity` in your code.